# Import 300 vCard files into LG v35 thinq

Tags: contacts

Is there an easy way to import 250+ vCard (vcf) files into my **LGv35 thinq** phone running **Android 8.0.0**, **Kernel version 4.9.65** and **Security patch level July 1, 2018**?

Firstly, the contacts app on my phone has no option to import contacts. Most examples I found online show how to use this "import contacts" that appears when you press the three dots on the top right after launching the Contacts app. The app, however, lets me browse through google contacts. Again, I don't see any options to import these into my phone.

```
A related question: Is there a way to import multiple .vcf files into gmail at once? 
The browser only lets me choose one file at a time.
```

The Phone app has a settings field and it too, doesn't have any options to import contacts.

I downloaded **Coolmuster Android assistant** and the option to import contacts requires me to buy the software.

I've successfully managed to download all the .vcf files into a folder on my phone. Is there a way to import all of them, at once, into my phone's memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply merge all .vcf files into one file. On Linux just use `cat *.vcf > all.vcf`.

Common software should support this all-in-one vcf file (e.g. GMail import). Just import it and all your contacts should be added.

Comment: Thanks Robert - I ended up concatenating all files into one, copying it over to my phone (using whatsapp) and successfully imported all contacts. It is so weird that most people that explained how to solve this problem totally ignored this simple fix.